# Some of the services are unable to be constructed in Asp.NET Core 6 which also uses Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on an Asp.NET core 6.0 project. I have added added the Microsoft's Identity classes to the project, which added the Razor pages. As a separate project added class library and added the Entity Framework's DataContext and IUnitOfWork and Repository pattern and registered the UnitOfWork in the Program.cs file. While it compiles fine, while running I am getting the following error:

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: eGrantsEvo.DataAccess.Repository.Interfaces.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: eGrantsEvo.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'eGrantsEvo.DataAccess.EGrantsEvoDbContext' while attempting to activate 'eGrantsEvo.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.)'

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'eGrantsEvo.DataAccess.EGrantsEvoDbContext' while attempting to activate 'eGrantsEvo.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.

```
    Program.cs:
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<EGrantsEvoDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(
            builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")
        ));

        builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => 
          options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EGrantsEvoDbContext>();
       

        builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        var app = builder.Build();

    IUnitOfWork:
    public interface IUnitOfWork
        {
           IUserRepository User { get; }
           void Save();
        }

    UnitOfWork:
     public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
        {
            private readonly EGrantsEvoDbContext _dbContext;
            public IUserRepository User { get; private set; }
   
            public UnitOfWork(EGrantsEvoDbContext dbContext)
            {
                    _dbContext = dbContext;
                    User = new UserRepository(_dbContext);

        }

        public void Save()
        {
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Have you try to put `builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();` before `AddDbContext`?

Comment: Tried it. Getting the same error!

Comment: Could you please tell me how and where you use the UnitOfWork ?

Comment: where is the registration of IUserRepository?